# Meaning of strong duality between max flow and min cut

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science, computer-science-theory

My question is about the max-flow and min-cut algorithm. I would like to know why there is strong duality between a max flow and a min cut?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem) Wikipedia article, the Max-Flow problem and the Min-Cut problem can be formulated as dual linear programs. As both linear programs are feasible, the duality can be seen as a special case of the [duality of linear programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Duality).